# tcsh `cd` always issues a printout of `$PWD`. How do I disable this?

Tags: tcsh, csh

Someone in IT thought it would be a good idea to modify the default behavior of the command `cd` in our tcsh environment.  As of Monday the "upgraded" version of `cd` always prints out `$PWD` after it navigates to the new directory.

e.g.

```
% cd ~/
Directory: /nfs/pdx/home/rbroger1
```

`which cd` yields no results so it isn't being alias'd.

Is there some environment variable or normal tcsh variable that is being set in our setup scripts to produce this output?  I don't want to change all my scripts to use a wrappered or alias'd `cd`.  I just want plain ol' `cd`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sounds like `cwdcmd` is set (man tcsh):

```
Runs after every change of working directory.
```